# Detect Finger Swipe in .Net Compact Framework

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, mobile, gesture-recognition

Looking for a way to detect finger gestures in my Windows Mobile applications. Main goal: detect when user gestures a left or right swipe across the screen. Similar to the swipe motion used to unlock an iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a flag when a [`MouseDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousedown(loband).aspx) event occurs, storing the position as well.

1. If you wish to react before the user removes his finger from the screen, listen to [`MouseMove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove(loband).aspx) events, and check the direction and distance relative to the `MouseDown` event that you require for an action to take place.
2. If you wish to wait for the user to remove his finger from the screen first, listen to [`MouseUp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseup(loband).aspx) events and check the direction and distance.

Comment: Those would be the basic steps, yes. But then the fun starts in interpreting the results, translating into command (messages) and suppressing the normal commands trhe mouse generates.